# How can I get integers from strings in my situation?

Tags: java

**Short story:** I generate random numbers and end symbol 0-9/ ( '/' is line end symbol, if I meet it, I go to write to next line in file.) When I generated my numbers and put in file, I want to get back those numbers from file but in not like strings, it should be Integers.

Assume my file looks like this:

```
846525451454341*
*
0067617354809629733035*
3313449117867514*
02337436891267261671546*
469980603887044*
7*
9*
642*
*
0617044835719095066*
5*
7175887168189821760*
581*
76300152922692817*
```

As you can noticed, line is able to hold only '*' in some cases (As I said it is generated random).

### **My purpose**

I want to get back these lines like integers. For example I take 1 line until I meet end symbol ( '/' ) then I loop another line and so on.

Some snippet:

```
 public void readGeneratedFile() throws IOException {
        try(BufferedReader r= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\java\\numbers.txt"))){
            int ch;
            s = new String();
            while((ch=r.read())!=-1){
               s+=String.valueOf(Character.toChars(ch)).replace(" ",""); // Here I take all file into String, But this approach is leading to boilerplate code;
                }
                    // catch IOException , finally close the file.
```

### **My question**

How can I get back those lines like integers? (Suppose I want to take some actions with those numbers) It's cool if you get an idea what I want to do.

Thanks.

### **EDITED:**

**Sorry for misunderstanding, It is not what I want. I want to get back separated values, For example I have 123456/564654/21 string, and my Integer array[1][index] should looks like 1,2,3,4,5,6 then I meet end line symbol '/' I jump to array[2][index] and fill it with next line in file.**

Comment: is `*` delimiter in file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this. also.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
         BigInteger integer;
        while (line != null) {
            line = line.replace("*","");
            integer = new BigInteger(line);
            //Your stuf
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

Comment: It is almost what I want, and it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your Strings are crossing the integer limit , You need [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html)

Ex

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("7175887168189821760");
```

And you cannot get it back like integers since they are crossing the limit.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
Integer.parseInt(String)
```

Since you have bigger values greater than what an Integer can store, you can go for 
`Long.parseLong(String)`

The other way is to use `BigInteger(String)` for working on the big numbers

Comment: That should be `Integer`

Comment: I know it man, but cannot get rid with an algorithm or approach how to use it in my situation.

Comment: But keep in mind that e.g. `Integer.parseInt("3313449117867514")` will throw an `NumberFormatException`, because `3313449117867514` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: I doubt if int can hold such big values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder as char accumulator (StringBuilder.append()) and finally

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());
```